# How to create ps1 PowerShell file in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, powershell

This is my first post:) Nice to get help

Is there any option to do that?
I attached screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can install `PowerShell tools for Visual Studio`.

You could install it from [Visual Studio gallery](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AdamRDriscoll.PowerShellToolsforVisualStudio2015). Once installed,
Create a new project , you will see PowerShell listed like below.
[image]

Below blog series will walk you though it.

https://pleasereleaseme.net/getting-started-with-powershell-tools-for-visual-studio/

Comment: Prasoon please at least summarize the steps required in the answer itself - answers where the meat of it is behind an external link usually don't age very well, since that blog post may go offline tomorrow, we'll never know :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Done and hope that suffice.

Comment: Yes, much better :)

Comment: Thank You Prasoon Very Much